# Is there a good way of writing a literal of binary data to write into a file?

Tags: c, file-io

I have bytes of a PDF file and I put them inside my C file.

The code then create a sample.pdf file and open it with wb to write those bytes into sample.pdf file.

It creates the file, but when opened it says the file has corrupted data.

Below I have attached my whole source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char docDat[] = "0x25,0x50,0x44,0x46,0x2D,0x31,0x2E,0x36,0x0A,0x25,0xC3,0xA4,0xC3,0xBC,0xC3,0xB6,0xC3,0x9F,0x0A,0x32,0x20,0x30,0x20,0x6F,0x62,0x6A,0x0A,0x3C,0x3C,0x2F,0x4C,0x65,0x6E,0x67,0x74,0x68,0x20,0x33,0x20,0x30,0x20,0x52,0x2F,0x46,0x69,0x6C,0x74,0x65,0x72,0x2F,0x46,0x6C,0x61,0x74,0x65,0x44,0x65 ..... Bytes of pdf";

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("sample.pdf", "wb");
    
    fprintf(fp, docDat);
    fclose(fp);


    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting that when the program is executed it creates a file named sample.pdf and write the bytes into it.

Comment: Your data is a string of a hexadecimal representation of bytes, not the bytes directly. Make an array of bytes instead of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte docDat[] = { 0x25, 0x50, ...  };
...
size_t actually_written = fwrite(docDat, 1, sizeof(docDat), fd);
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite

Instead of `byte` often `unsigned char` is used. The first 4 bytes spell "%PDF".